# Excel calculated column based on substring value

Tags: excel

I have a column in a spreadsheet called Title. It has data like this:

```
Exam Review for-Mr. Donald Trump [ID:1187389, Eve: 151024]
```

The value can have many different values but I want to create a calculated column where any value that begins with "Exam Review" will have ONLY "Exam Review" in it.
Columns with other data will have the same data in the calculated column.

Any ideas? This calculated column is going to be used in a pivot table.

Comment: You have definitely been here long enough to know you have to show effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is in column A:

```
=IF(LEFT(A2,11)="Exam Review","Exam Review","A2")
```

Comment: How to make it get the current row? The column needed is C

Comment: You mean, if your data is in `C` instead of `A`? Replace `A` with `C` and paste the above in your sheet.

Comment: Yeah, I got it. The spreadsheet I had was filtered and I couldn't see all rows.